# Continuous Time LTI system stability confusion

Tags: transfer-function, stability, pole-zeroplot

It is understood that if ROC of the transfer function of a system doesn’t not contain the \$j\omega\$ axis, then the system is unstable.

I also know that if the transfer function of the system has any RHS poles, the system will be unstable.

But what about a system with only one pole, which lies in the RHS of the s plane but has a left sided ROC (anti-causal behaviour). This system has both: a pole in the RHS and an ROC that contains the \$j\omega\$ axis. So is it stable or unstable?

What is this contradiction? What am I missing?

Comment: Why not model it in a circuit simulator? That's what I might consider doing.